# Linux (unabel to find the missing memory)?

Tags: linux, memory-management

I am wondering about the linux missing memory, i am trying to find missing memory on linux box but unable to find it, where missing gone ? below are some details..

I have Linux (CentOs-6.7) VPS with 15GB RAM,on which ruby-on-rails application / apache is running, below is the current usage of memory.

```
> [root@myvps ~]# free -m  
                     total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached  
        Mem:         14941      11295       3645          0        146        801  
        -/+ buffers/cache:      10347       4594   
        Swap:         4095          0       4095
```

-/+ buffers/cache = 10347 (approx 10GB is currently used memory)

> [root@myvps ~]# cat /proc/meminfo
>   MemTotal:       15299820 kB
>   MemFree:         3733272 kB
>   Buffers:          150368 kB
>   Cached:           821256 kB
>   SwapCached:            0 kB
>   Active:          1120800 kB
>   Inactive:         293316 kB
>   Active(anon):     442520 kB
>   Inactive(anon):      180 kB
>   Active(file):     678280 kB
>   Inactive(file):   293136 kB
>   Unevictable:           0 kB
>   Mlocked:               0 kB
>   SwapTotal:       4194300 kB
>   SwapFree:        4194300 kB
>   Dirty:                36 kB
>   Writeback:             0 kB
>   AnonPages:        442508 kB
>   Mapped:            15008 kB
>   Shmem:               212 kB
>   Slab:              77340 kB
>   SReclaimable:      44512 kB
>   SUnreclaim:        32828 kB
>   KernelStack:        4992 kB
>   PageTables:         7328 kB
>   NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
>   Bounce:                0 kB
>   WritebackTmp:          0 kB
>   CommitLimit:    11844208 kB
>   Committed_AS:     736300 kB
>   VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
>   VmallocUsed:      183576 kB
>   VmallocChunk:   34351291740 kB
>   HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
>   AnonHugePages:    186368 kB
>   HugePages_Total:       0
>   HugePages_Free:        0
>   HugePages_Rsvd:        0
>   HugePages_Surp:        0
>   Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
>   DirectMap4k:       10240 kB
>   DirectMap2M:    15718400 kB

Now i want to check / confirm about which process taking used memory..

I count the sum of all process RES (rss)

[root@myvps ~]# ps axo pid,rss,cmd  | awk '{sum+=$2} END {print sum / 1024}'
**706.441**

Now as **per (RES) we have 706MB** is currently using which is less than 1GB

Now i check the slab memory from /proc/meminfo as pasted above..

Slab:              77340 kB
SReclaimable:      44512 kB
SUnreclaim:        32828 kB

so we have 77MB slab memory is currently using in which 44MB is reclaimable. So total used memory = 706.411MB + 77.3MB = **783.711MB**

So the final figure is (Total used memory - RES (for all process) + slabmemory **(10347 - 783.711MB = 9563.289)**

Now the missing memory 9563, approx 9+GB , dont know where is the missing memory gone ? or which process using that memory ?

Only reboot is the option to recover that missing memory, but after passage of time missing memory ratio will increase rapidly. I have read the below threads also, but still unable to find the real cause.

http://www.logicmonitor.com/blog/2014/10/09/more-linux-memory-free-memory-that-is-not-free-nor-cache/

https://techtalk.intersec.com/2013/07/memory-part-2-understanding-process-memory/

Kindly please help & suggest for further troubleshoot..

Thanks
Mike.

Comment: In the lines above I can see: -/+ buffers/cache = 10347 (approx 10GB is currently used memory) doesn't this mean that the missing memory is actually being used by the kernel for buffer/cache? .. have you tried to free up this memory? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87908/how-do-you-empty-the-buffers-and-cache-on-a-linux-system

Comment: 11295 is the current used memory, from which subtracts -/+buffers/cache  = 10347MB , so clearing cache is useless. I already tried that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux memory reporting discrepancy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463800/linux-memory-reporting-discrepancy)

Comment: You may want to check this thread: http://superuser.com/questions/308006/how-to-find-out-what-process-are-eating-all-memory